# Bind multiple tables to a DataGridView in .net and sql server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, view, strongly-typed-dataset

I am working on a project to manage the inventory of a small business. I have a database with SQL server 2014 that contains several tables including: "Inventory", "Product", "Location", "Department", "Provider".

I am currently using the offline method ado.net. I can't use LINQ :(

I need to select certain fields from 5 tables listed above and bind them to a `DataGridView`.

For example, I want to take code, description, tax, price from Product; Quantity, company from Inventory; Description from Location; DepartmentCode from Department; providerCode from Provider; and bind all those fields to one `DataGridView`.

I'm currently using a "strongly typed dataset" that contains my entire database.

I did some research before asking a question here. Some people say to take all the information and deposit in a `DataTable`. Is it the good way? Is there a better way to do it? Maybe I can use stored procedure?

In addition, the information in the datagridview can be updated!

If you need more information, just ask it!

Comment: For getting application work, DataTable can be good start. It even automatically can be bounded to the DataGridView.

Comment: You should use sql Views to join all this information, you cannot bind multiples tables, do this work in sql.

Comment: You dont bind to database tables, but to a `DataTable` which can be comprised of fileds from various db tables

Comment: A lot depends on if and how you need to update. The simplest way is to create a dataset from a JOIN query and bind your grid to that via a BindingSource.

Comment: Yes, the datagridview can be updated. In this case, the view is not a good option, right?

Comment: If you want to make the grid updateable itself then this is more difficult. Personally I am not a fan of that from a UI perspective either - I prefer to have a separate edit window that pops up when the user double-clicks a row in the grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create an sql view from the command that join all these tables. And use it as a source of a tableadapter in the dataset designer.

You can use stored procedure but it is not best practice because views provide more features like indexes.

Comment: I agree with you, best performance is through views, and creating index on top of the view